# Using ElasticSearch as a permanent storage

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hbase

Recently I am working on a project which is producing a huge amount of data every day, in this project, there are two functionalities, one is storing data into Hbase for future analysis, and second one is pushing data into ElasticSearch for monitoring. 
As the data is huge,  we should store data into two platforms(Hbase,Elasticsearch)!
I have no experience in both of them. I want no know is it possible to use elasticsearch instead of hbase as a persistence storage for future analytics?

Comment: Elasticsearch will start failing when you reach a large amount of indices (upwards of 40, I've seen)

Comment: This will depend on the ressources of your cluster and a few other factors, but 40 is a rather random number (also it's generally the number of shards that is the relevant number)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you reading this old but still valid article : https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-as-nosql
Keep in mind, Elasticsearch is only a search engine. But it depends if your data are critical or if you can accept to lose some of them like non critical logs.
If you don't want to use an additionnal database with huge large data, you probably can store them into files in something like HDFS.

Comment: Plus, ES-Hadoop can pull data between systems

Comment: Although we have some critical data and we don’t like to lose any of them, so your means is I should use some nosql databases?

Answer (score 0):

You should also check Phoenix https://phoenix.apache.org/ which may provide the monitoring features that you are looking for